# Query string searches from AWS database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, fetch

I am querying an AWS database of users with a search input, fetch and react hooks. In order to get it working, I had to set up a separate express server and make the fetch request to this, as there are CORS issues with AWS with little way to get around it.

My fetch request...

```
    const getUsers = async (query) => {
        const results = await fetch(`http://localhost:3005/search?`)      
        const userData = await results.json()
        console.log("this is the results", results, "this is the data", userData);

        return userData.results
    }
```

If I hard code the query on the express server like so...

```
const express = require('express'); 
const request = require('request'); 
const app = express();

app.get('/search', function(req, res, query){ 
    request(`https://search-*****-*****.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=bob`, function (error, response, body) { 
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) { 
        console.log(body); 
        res.send(body); 
      } 
     }); 
  });

  app.listen(3005); 
console.log('Server running on port %d', 3005);
```

It works, console output is...

```
status: {rid: "****", time-ms: 1}
hits:
found: 1
start: 0
hit: [{…}]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

With hits being an array of the user for Bob, however when I pass in a query string to my fetch
request, it doesn't return any results

```
    const getUsers = async (query) => {
        const results = await fetch(`http://localhost:3005/search?q=${query}`)      
        const userData = await results.json()
        console.log("this is the results", results, "this is the data", userData);

        return userData.results
    }
```

```
const express = require('express'); 
const request = require('request'); 
const app = express();

app.get('/search', function(req, res, query){ 
    request(`https://search-*****-*****.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search`, function (error, response, body) { 
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) { 
        console.log(body); 
        res.send(body); 
      } 
     }); 
  });

  app.listen(3005); 
console.log('Server running on port %d', 3005);
```

It doesn't return any hits...

```
status: {rid: "****", time-ms: 1}
hits:
found: 0
start: 0
hit: [{…}]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

I'm sure the best way to query is to have it in my fetch request but I'm not sure why it's not working. If anyone can shed any light I'd be grateful.

Comment: where you are passing your query in second request https://search-*****-*****.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search  ?

Comment: within the fetch request 
        const results = await fetch(`http://localhost:3005/search?q=${query}`)

Comment: created an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing  http://localhost:3005/search?q=${query} this from frontend but not using that as req.query.q in aws url.

```
const express = require('express'); 
    const request = require('request'); 
    const app = express();

    app.get('/search', function(req, res, query){ 
        request(`https://search-*****-*****.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=`+req.query.q, function (error, response, body) { 
          if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) { 
            console.log(body); 
            res.send(body); 
          } 
         }); 
      });

      app.listen(3005); 
    console.log('Server running on port %d', 3005);
```